# Ajax SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Ok people. I got this error and i tried all the solutions people with the same problem used to solve it. Nothing.
I need to use jQuery "ajax" function to get some data from a php and then distribute the data in some inputs. If i use 'text' as dataType it works like a charm, but with the json dataType i get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

My code is:

**js**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
        url: globals.rootdir + '/controller.php?op=do_something&module=56',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            year: previouslyDeclaredYearVar
        },

            success: function (data) {

                alert('good');

        },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);

            }
    });
```

**php - the controller do_something function**

```
if (!isAjaxRequest()){
    return;
  }
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    ... do things
    echo json_encode(['result'=>'test-ajax-ok']);
```

Comment: Most likly you got an error in your php code, whichs corrupts your json format. Or you got php warnings.

Comment: What `data` is returned to your `success` handler?

Comment: check for whitespace in output by looking at the browser console network tab.

Comment: Did you try to accept the data as string and just see what's wrong with it instead of letting $ try to parse it for you... with the "datatype" I mean.

Comment: Also dont use `alert` use `console.log()`, and learn to live in your developer tools window ;p

Comment: What happens if you remove the `header("Content-type: application/json");` before the echo? It shouldn't be needed in my experience.

Comment: What doe the JSON data look like, without seeing that its just guessing, it could be as simple as `\s<?php` a space or line return in front of a PHP open/close tag (those get output too).

Comment: @Dave - actually some browsers will return `data` as a json string without the correct header, then you have to manually parse it, some older browsers will try to download it as a file with it ... :-/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix interesting ... thanks for the info. I'm guessing they would be old(er) browsers that would do that?

Comment: Yea I think it was either IE8 or IE9 maybe that would download it as a file if you put the header in,  I typically put it in now so I cant say which current once would not recognize it as proper JSON,  Ive been doing web development sense 2008 so there was a time I had to deal with even IE6 ... (which was old even then, but still used) lol, the hours I spend on that browser alone are ridiculous.

Comment: Typically what I do now is something like `function(data){ if(typeof data == 'string' ){ try{ data = $.parseJSON(data); }catch(e){ data = {'error' : e.message, 'body' : data}; }` that way if it's JSON it's fine, if it's a string it tries to parse it, if it cant then a `data.error` gets set (I use that for serverside errors ) then I put the contents of the string data in a property.  That way if its a serverside error that wasn't properly caught and wrapped in JSON I have something to look at.  That covers most of the stuff. I typically use the `.allways` callback for 404 and such errors too

Comment: @Dave i tried that already.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i'll try that and i'll let you know

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit No, 'cause it works if i change the dataType to 'text'

Comment: Pleas Check the request fromm the Server with the Debugging tools of your Browser. Your Error is an typical wrong formated Json String.